# Maven facet version issue in web application

Tags: java, maven-3, m2eclipse

I am trying to create a maven web app, which will be part of my maven ear application. I tried creating web app from command line as well as from option within eclipse but both ways giving me error like "Dynamic Web Module 3.1 requires Java 1.7 or newer." I tried changing build path JDK to Java 1.8 and compiler level to 1.8 and saved but this didn't resolve the issue. When I do right click on project "maven update", the JDK again getting reset to old one not sure why it's not saving my changes. Is it issue with eclipse(I tried both LUNA and MARS version of eclipse)? How to resolve this issue as it's not letting me run my application from eclipse.

Also I am getting this access restriction warning "Access restriction: The type 'XmlElement' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar')". If I remove JDK from build path and add it again it disappears. But when maven update is done error reappears. Please someone suggest me how to resolve these issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following in pom.xml and do maven update

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```